# How can i ignore some path of vaadin ? /HEARTBEAT /UIDL /VAADIN

Tags: spring, vaadin

I am using a vaadin application with the dashboardemo example

My class does not use a VaadinSevlet but, a **VaadinCDIServlet**

My webServlet 3.0 I have it so

```
@WebServlet (asyncSupported = false, urlPatterns = {"/*"},
```

I will not serve any static content otherwise I would write another

urlpattern as well /VAADIN/*

The problem is that when I visit the path as

```
/HEARTBEAT/?v-uid=0
/HEARTBEAT
/UIDL/?v-uiId=2
/VAADIN/
/VAADIN/themes/valo/fonts
```

I get different errors, as I can show some errorView or redirect users to a main view,

The demo dashboard actually redirects some incorrect url or fragments **!#blalbla**, redirect to

```
https://domain/myapp/#!dashboard
```

but with these path does not it, I have reviewed many applications and it happens just the same, whether we are demos or not.please some help?

**Update**

The solution I recommend for this in case of handling errors 4xx 5xx etc, is to use spring framework, example:. redirect to an external url

```
@RestController
public class MyController implements ErrorController {

private static final String URL = "http://www.blablaba.com";

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public void handle(final RuntimeException rex, final HttpServletResponse 
hsp) throws IOException {
    hsp.sendRedirect(getErrorPath());
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {
    return URL;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure the approach they took in the demo but this is what comes to my mind. In your `ErrorView` you can call `UI.getCurrent().getNavigator()` and  then redirect to the desired URL by getting the URL from the `Page.getCurrent()` object then running `Navigator.navigateTo()`.

Comment: Hi, how are you? Sorry but since the original source code, and that part that you comment is implemented, and it does not work for what I want, I can not do anything when a user visits these directories / VAADIN and the others

Comment: After thinking about this. I don't think its possible to redirect these pages. These urls are what provide the css javascript and all the important bits. Now if you where to redirect these pages then the browser couldn't load this information for vaadin to work. Vaadin.com also has a nice forum you can post this to where the vaadin devs themselves can respond.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed I appreciate it, I imagine that also because they are resources. I create a thread on this subject too and no one helped me.